# When input type="image", onclick action was triggered by hitting enter from another input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code, I made a JavaScript function which will delete the current row from a table. Then in HTML I put that function into an 'input' element which will trigger the function in an 'onclick' action. Everything works fine if I make the input type="button", but if I make it  type="image" as you can see below, even with "return false;", whenever I press enter in any of the input field in the same row, it will trigger the delete function.

I don't know why.

```
 function deleteRow(r)
{   
var rowLength= document.getElementById("newOrder").rows.length; //get how many rows are in this table

if (rowLength == 2)  //if there are only two rows (including header), then don't allow to delete a row
{
    alert ("At least one row is needed to create an order.");
    return;
} else  //if row number is greater than 2, then delete a row is allowed
{
var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("newOrder").deleteRow(i);
}
```

following is the HTML code

```
        <tr>
        <td class="item"><input type="image" onclick="deleteRow(this); return false;" src="img/delete.png" height="20" width="20" alt="delete"><input type="text" class="biginput, item"  ></td>
        <td class="detail"><input class="detail" type="number" ></td>
        <td class="detail"><input class="detail" type="number" ></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Separate advice - I personally see no reason to *ever* use `input type="image"` any more, because you can use the newer (and more semantic) `<button><img src="..."><button>` and *any* HTML can go within the `<button> anything </button>` — see [When To Use The Button Element](http://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/). Buttons are especially good for when an action (like deleteRow) takes place. See [Links are not buttons. Neither are DIVs and SPANs](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried using a button but because the image resolution is 20 x 20, seems like the button frame itself is much larger than the image, and I found no way to size a button. Any suggestion?

Comment: A button is a general HTML element and can be completely styled, along with the markup within it that can be completely styled. That said, although I could probably twiddle with it to do what I wanted, it may not fit your case and I can't write a whole article here. Read the articles I linked in my earlier comment, and consider `<button>` when you work on this sort of thing. Not everything fits every situation, but if you broaden your knowledge you can make better, more informed decisions. It's in that vein that I (myself) no longer have any use for `input type="image"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: [Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Lnm/2/)

```
<form>
    <input id="image" onclick="return deleteRow(this);" type="image" src="img/delete.png" height="20" width="20" alt="delete" />
</form>
```

Using pure javascript:

```
function deleteRow(instance) {
    alert("delete");
    return false;
}
```

Using jquery as you have tagged jquery in your post:

```
$('#image').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // yaa!
alert("delete");
});
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning both `return false` and `.preventDefault()` — I've found a good article on the difference between the two, but (sadly) can't find it right now.